# Flex3 Improving basic trace

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, debugging, trace, logging

I read somewhere a utils to show the class + line nbr of the function who called a trace("foo") which is very handy once you start getting a lot of debug output.

Any hints on where to find it ? it was open source, maybe shown at a flex event.

```
trace("my debug");

> mydebug :34 bla.as3 ..
```

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick&dirty solution:

```
    private function mytrace(s:String):void {
        try {
            throw new Error();
        } catch (e:Error) {
            var arr:Array = e.getStackTrace().split("\n", 3);
            trace(arr[2] + " " + s);
        }
    }
```

For mytrace("xyz") you will get:

```
at Main/init() xyz
```

or if you compile with "-debug=true":

```
at Main/init()[C:\home\myproject\Main.mxml:120] xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a package like that before but you might get lucky searching google's codesearch with a well devised regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to Haxe (http://haxe.org), which is an open source programming language very similar to ActionScript.

They don't have a browser-accesible repository but you can download the sources following the instructions here http://haxe.org/download.

I did manage to find something on Google Code Search:

- http://code.google.com/p/haxecli/source/browse/trunk/haxe/std/haxe/Log.hx
- http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Pm0PKVV_vso/trunk/haxe/std/haxe/Log.hx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/buzz) yet ? It's quite comprehensive, easy to install, and showed a lot more than just the trace statements - see the features pages on the site for an overview.

I've tried it, but it was too rich for my taste and I went back to simple trace statements - my programs aren't that complex yet !